# How to use from_statement with pagination in SQLalchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a complex query `sql = "SELECT title, name, country FROM ..."`, which I execute using

```
results = db.session.query("title", "name", "country").from_statement(text(sql)).all()
```

This works and produces the desired results. I would like to paginate this query, but

```
results = db.session.query("title", "name", "country").from_statement(text(sql)).paginate(1,10, False)
```

gives me the error `AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'paginate'`. I have successfully used `paginate()` elsewhere in my code, but never with the `from_statement()`. How can I do this?

Comment: Assuming that you used Flask-SQLAlchemy, the paginate is actually implemented in the [`BaseQuery.paginate`](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/api.html#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.BaseQuery.paginate) and not in the default SQLAlchemy Query which is used in your code. Also, I do not think you will be able to use paginate on the fully constructed SQL statement produced by `text(...)`.